# Can't call Ajax function from my php script, working with live table it

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, jquery

I'm working on this project that uses a live table edit style (works perfectly) but trying to include the twitter style follow and unfollow in one of the columns (The last one precisely) the php works well but I've having problems returning the data to ajax to post to another php script.

Below shows the major part of the script (The php and ajax). I included a php comment on the important area of interest.

```
<?php  $query_pag_data = "SELECT * FROM applicant_result WHERE year='$year' AND  
class='$class' ORDER by candidate_no ";  $uid=strip_tags($id);
$result_pag_data = mysql_query($query_pag_data) or die('MySql Error' . mysql_error());
$finaldata = "";
$tablehead= '';
$tablehead= "<tr>
    <th class='data'>#</th>
    <th  class='data'>Applicant ID</th>
    <th class='data'>Year</th>
    <th class='data'>Class</th>
    <th class='data'>$subject_1</th>
    <th class='data'>$subject_2</th>
    <th class='data'>$subject_3</th>
    <th class='data'>$subject_4</th>
    <th class='data'>$subject_5</th>
    <th class='data'>Total</th>
    <th class='data'>Status</th>
    <th class='data'>Interview</th>
    </tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result_pag_data)) {
$id=htmlentities($row['candidate_no']);
$subject_1=htmlentities($row['subject_1']);
$subject_2=htmlentities($row['subject_2']);
$subject_3=htmlentities($row['subject_3']);
$subject_4=htmlentities($row['subject_4']);
$subject_5=htmlentities($row['subject_5']);
$total=htmlentities($row['total']);
$status=htmlentities($row['interview']);
$uid= strip_tags($row['candidate_no']);

/* HELLO FORUMITES, THIS IS THE MAJOR AREA OF FOCUS HERE */

if($status!=0){$button="
<span id='loading<?php echo $uid; ?>'></span>
        <span class='button following' id='following<?php echo $uid; ?>' `onClick='follow_or_unfollow(<?php echo $uid; ?>,'following');'>Following</span>`

<span style='display:none;' class='button follow' id='follow<?php
         echo $uid; ?>' onClick='follow_or_unfollow(<?php echo $uid; ?>,'follow');'>Follow</span>
";}
else{
$button="
<span id='loading<?php echo $uid; ?>'></span>
        <span class='button follow' id='follow<?php echo $uid; ?>' 
onClick='follow_or_unfollow(<?php echo $uid; ?>,'follow');'>Follow</span>

        <span class='button following' style='display:none;'`id='following<?php echo $uid; ?>' onClick='follow_or_unfollow(<?php echo $uid;` ?>,'following');'>Following</span>
";}

$tabledata.="<tr id='$id' class='edit_tr'>

<td class='edit_td' ><span class='text'>$counter</span></td>
<td class='edit_td' ><span class='text'>$id</span></td>
<td class='edit_td' ><span class='text'>$year</span>
<input type='hidden' value='$year' class='editbox' id='six_input_$id' /></td>

<td class='edit_td' ><span class='text'>$class</span>
<input type='hidden' value='$class' class='tbox' id='seven_input_$id' /></td>

<td class='edit_td' >
<span id='one_$id' class='text'>$subject_1</span>
<input type='text' value='$subject_1' class='editbox' id='one_input_$id' /></td>

<td class='edit_td' ><span id='two_$id' class='text'>$subject_2</span> 
<input type='text' value='$subject_2' class='editbox' id='two_input_$id'/></td>

<td class='edit_td' ><span id='three_$id' class='text'>$subject_3 </span>
<input type='text' value='$subject_3' class='editbox' id='three_input_$id'/></td>

<td class='edit_td' ><span id='four_$id' class='text'>$subject_4</span>
<input type='text' value='$subject_4' class='editbox' id='four_input_$id' /></td>

<td class='edit_td' ><span id='five_$id' class='text'>$subject_5</span>
<input type='text' value='$subject_5' class='editbox' id='five_input_$id' /></td>

<td class='edit_td' ><span class='text'>$total</span></td>

<td class='edit_td' ><span class='text'>$status</span></td>

<td>$button </td> 

</tr>";

$counter++;
}

$finaldata = "<table width='100%'>".$tablehead." ".$tabledata. "</table>"; 

echo $finaldata;
```

**NOW THE AJAX**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.following').hover(function() {
            $(this).text('Unfollow');
        }, function() {
            $(this).text("Following");
        });
    });

    function follow_or_unfollow(id, action) {
        var dataString = "id=" + id;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "follow_or_unfollow.php",
            data: dataString,
            beforeSend: function() {
                if (action == "following") {
                    $("#following" + id).hide();
                    $("#loading" + id).html('<img src="loading.gif" align="absmiddle" alt="Loading...">');
                }
                else if (action == "follow") {
                    $("#follow" + id).hide();
                    $("#loading" + id).html('<img src="loading.gif" align="absmiddle" alt="Loading...">');
                }
            },
            success: function(response) {
                if (action == "following") {
                    $("#loading" + id).html('');
                    $("#follow" + id).show();
                }
                else if (action == "follow") {
                    $("#loading" + id).html('');
                    $("#following" + id).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }

</script>
```

Comment: And what exactly 'doesn't work'? I appreciate that you're sharing your code, but a bit of an explanation as to what you're expecting it to do and what it actually does would be nice.

Comment: In the first couple of lines of your php you are referring to $class, $year, and $id. $id should maybe be $_POST['id']. I don't see where $class or $year are defined.

Comment: REFUGNIC ETERNIUM: When i click the follow button, the ajax doesn't respond
GENERAL: The above php script was included in another php script i.e (include'abovescript.php' ;) from which the variables were all defined.

The major problem is how to retrive the onclick function data via ajax to the link follow_or_unfollow.php

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your ajax type to GET `type: "GET",`
Also how are you receiving your global at the other end of the php
Did you used `GET` or `POST`?

Comment: Refugnic Eternium: When i click the follow button, the ajax doesn't respond
GENERAL: The above php script was included in another php script i.e (include'abovescript.php' ;) from which the variables were all defined.

The major problem is how to retrive the onclick function data via ajax to the link follow_or_unfollow.php

FrancisMarfo Tried GET but didn't work

@ioums: Those variables were c